# Execution default-cli of goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start failed: String index out of range: -6

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, jgit

my project uses jgit to release the code to artifactory , how ever suddenly am facing the issue as Execution default-cli of goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start failed: String index out of range: -6
using below plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <flowInitContext>
                        <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
                        <developBranchName>develop</developBranchName>
                    </flowInitContext>
                    <username>xxxxxx</username>
                    <password>xxxxx</password>
                    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: This plugin looks too old... of 2015... better use a more recent plugin https://search.maven.org/search?q=jgitflow-maven-plugin

Comment: i went through the above link and it shows thats the latest version